# Unexpected behaviour with constructors

Tags: c++

Simple program:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace::std;


class X {
    public:
        X() {
            cout << "Default Constructor called\n";
            i = 0;
        }


        X(int i) {
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor called\n";
            this->i = i;
        }
        X(const X& x) {
            cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
            i = x.getI();
        }
        ~X() {
            cout << "Destructor called\n";
        }
        int getI() const {
            return i;
        }
        X func() {
            cout << "Entered func\n";
            X x(2);
            return x;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

int main() {
     X x1;
     X x2 = x1.func();
    cout << "Returned from func\n";    
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
Default Constructor called
Entered func
Parameterized Constructor called
Copy Constructor called
Destructor called
Returned from func
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

**My issue is that after the 'Returned from func' is printed, no constructor is called when creating the instance x2. I was actually expecting a copy constructor to be called when instantiating x2 as it would have been if we did something like `X x2 = x1;`**

Answer (score 2):

I initially incorrectly assumed that the reason was RVO, so I keep my original answer below.

What your program prints is expected. Note that you print "Returned from function" **after** you call it and assign the returned value to `x2`. So the order of prints is correct: it first instantiates `x`, hence parametrized ctor call, then it copies it to `x2`, as it exits from the function, then it calls the destructor of `x`, which is no longer needed, then it actually exits from the function, and only then it reaches your print statement.

Old answer follows

---

What you observe is Return Value Optimization.

> Return value optimization, or simply RVO, is a compiler optimization
>   technique that involves eliminating the temporary object created to
>   hold a function's return value.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) In C++, it is particularly notable
>   for being allowed to change the observable behaviour of the resulting
>   program.[2]

> In general, the C++ standard allows a compiler to perform any
>   optimization, provided the resulting executable exhibits the same
>   observable behaviour as if (i.e. pretending) all the requirements of
>   the standard have been fulfilled. This is commonly referred to as the
>   "as-if rule".[3] The term return value optimization refers to a
>   special clause in the C++ standard which goes even further than the
>   "as-if" rule: an implementation may omit a copy operation resulting
>   from a return statement, even if the copy constructor has side
>   effects.[4]

See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), it has an example that is very similar to yours

Comment: Please explain clearly. I don't know what optimization is. Please spoon feed me this one time. :(

Comment: Follow the link that I posted, I can't explain better than wikipedia :)

Comment: Hmmm...ok. Thank you. I love you.

Comment: I posted a slightly bigger quote from wikipedia, so that the answer is mostly self-contained

Comment: Woah wait!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! In wiki, it said, `

Return value optimization, or simply RVO, is a compiler optimization technique that involves eliminating the temporary object created to hold a function's return value` but x2 here is not a temporary object...so what now?

Comment: Yes, `x` in your function is the temporary object. What you expect to happen is `x` to get created, and then, as the function returns, copied to `x2`. Instead the compiler eliminates that temporary object, and instantiates your instance of `X` directly inside `x2`, eliminating the temporary object `x` and the need to call the copy constructor

Comment: No, you are wrong. check the order of the print statements.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, then the output seems right to me. Why do you expct any copy constructors to be called after "Returned from function", if you print "Returned from function" after you assign the returned value to `x2`? There's one copy ctor call in your output, and that's precisely the copy from `x` to `x2` as the function exits. I also updated my answer